# AWS static site routing nested resources and custom URLs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a static site hosted on Amazon S3 that works great so far.  For now I just have simple routes that are directly mapped to the html files that are served Eg

```
index.html
login
faq
```

How do I add more complicated routing for nested resources though?  If I want to add `/users/bob` I could create a folder called users and create an html page for every single user but that's absurd.  What's the proper way of doing this?  Follow up question for nested resources like `/users/bob/things/1`?

Comment: I thought the routing rules on s3 static sites were the same as nginx configuration rules, but maybe I'm wrong.  I'm not using a client side framework - otherwise all traffic would be routed to index.html and that would handle the routing

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HowDoIWebsiteConfiguration.html has the redirect rules

Comment: When a new user bob signs up I should not have to upload a new html file called bob to s3 at /users/bob.  There should be one html file hosted at /users/user that accepts all traffic to /users/*

Comment: I already know how to do it with using get parameters very easily by uploading a file users and then accepting routes to /users?username=bob  I was just wondering if it was doable with custom URLs

Comment: Jquery reads the get parameters on page load and makes an ajax call to load the user content.

Comment: So you are loading dynamic content, from somewhere other than S3 I take it, using JQuery. That's the kind of information that you need to include in your question so we understand what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch of reading it looks like the simplest solution for me is converting my site to a single page app.  Rather than learning a whole new framework I'm going to try this 100 line javascript url router http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/A-modern-JavaScript-router-in-100-lines-history-api-pushState-hash-url and http://handlebarsjs.com/ for templates